# How can I trigger AMP development mode without a URL

Tags: amp-html

I'm building some tooling for the design of AMP pages. According to [the docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate.html), one should add `#development=1` to the URL of a pages to trigger validations.

The tooling I've written generates an AMP HTML document and uses an iframe `srcdoc` attribute to render it on the fly. Thus there is no URL. Is there another way to trigger validations and development mode?

Answer (score 3):

Per the comment at https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/999#issuecomment-171787638, the validator can be used programmatically. A demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4yoxog13/5/

I believe this validator is the official one, [source code here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/validator).

```
Some code because stackoverflow wants there to be code.
```